# Replace new lines character which are in quotas in file using sed

Tags: unix, sed

I have been exported file from open office to csv. But the long text in cell have new line characters. The rows with cell with text looks like this in csv

```
;;;;ddsfaads;;dsfaadsfdas;"
dfsafdas
fdadfsdaf
fddsfaadfs
fdsfadsadsfadf
"
```

how to do it?

Comment: ;;;;ddsfaads;;dsfaadsfdas;"dfsafdas fdadfsdaf fddsfaadfs fdsfadsadsfadf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use this way also ,

```
sed '/"/{:a;N;/\n.*"/{s/\n/ /g;p;d;t};s/\n/ /g; t a};' FileName
```

Answer (score 0):

Some  like this?

```
cat file
test
;;;;ddsfaads;;dsfaadsfdas;"
dfsafdas
fdadfsdaf
fddsfaadfs
fdsfadsadsfadf
"
more data
```

```
awk '/"/ {f=f?0:1} {printf "%s%s",$0,(f?FS:RS)}' file
test
;;;;ddsfaads;;dsfaadsfdas;" dfsafdas fdadfsdaf fddsfaadfs fdsfadsadsfadf "
more data
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer in the internet.

```
sed -n 'H;g;/^[^"]*"[^"]*\("[^"]*"[^"]*\)*$/d; s/^\n//; y/\n/ /; p; s/.*//; h' 'filefrom' > 'fileto'
```

It works for me